# How to convert a single Subversion project to Mercurial repository?

Tags: svn, mercurial, mercurial-convert

I have an old **Subversion repository** with **many projects** inside it. Each of the project follows the canonical **trunk-branches-tags** convention for SVN.

I can convert the entire SVN repository to Mercurial using:

```
$ hg convert /some-path/old-svn-rep
# This creates old-svn-rep-hg

$ cd old-svn-rep-hg
$ hg update
# Can see all the projects as separate directories
```

If you know SVN, you know that the directory organization inside `/some-path/old-svn-rep` is:

```
$ ls /some-path/old-svn-rep
conf/
db/
hooks/
locks/
format
README.txt
```

How do I **convert a single project** inside this SVN repository, say named **Foo**, into a Mercurial repository?

This obviously does not work:

```
$ hg convert /some-path/old-svn-rep/Foo
assuming destination Foo-hg
initializing destination Foo-hg repository
/some-path/old-svn-rep/Foo does not look like a Subversion repository
```

Please assume that the SVN project has changes in the trunk, many branches and tags.

Answer (score 1):

`hg convert` can take any URL that you would use to checkout the project in the SVN repository.

In my tests, `svn checkout /some-path/old-svn-repo/Foo` doesn't work either.  What you need to do is prefix it with `file://` if you are cloning something from the local filesystem - i.e. `svn checkout file:///some-path/old-svn-repo/Foo`

It is the same for `hg convert` so try `hg convert file:///some-path/old-svn-repo/Foo`

Comment: Steve: I have the same problem using `file://`.

Comment: Have you got three '/'s in there? two for the `file://` and one for the start of the path.  I'd try checking the project out using `svn` and copy that exact path into the `hg convert` statement - it should work.

Answer (score 0):

HGSubversion extension and clone SVN-repo (`hg clone`) **from project root**

Answer (score 0):

I was able to do this with the following steps:

```
svnadmin create Foo
```

I needed to alter this command as I did not have access to the svn server so the versions didn't match during clone:

```
svnadmin create --compatible-version 1.6 Foo
```

Follow steps 1-5 here: [howto use svnsync to mirror a repository on windows](http://iacoware.wordpress.com/2009/10/02/howto-use-svnsync-to-mirror-a-repository-on-windows/)

```
svnsync init file:///projects/Foo /some-path/old-svn-rep/Foo
svnsync sync file:///projects/Foo
```

Follow step 2 here to create usermapping.txt: [Goodbye Subversion, Hello Mercurial: A Migration Guide](https://blogs.atlassian.com/2011/03/goodbye_subversion_hello_mercurial/)

Install hgsubversion: [hgsubversion](https://bitbucket.org/durin42/hgsubversion/wiki/Home)

```
hg clone --config extensions.hgsubversion=/path-to-hgsubversion / 
--config hgsubversion.authormap=usermapping.txt / 
file:///projects/Foo hg-Foo
```